# How to get the URL to a Google Cloud Storage file using gcloud-node?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud-node

Using the [gcloud Node library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node), how do I get the URL for a file within a Cloud Storage bucket?

Consider the following instantation of a file object:

```
let bucket = gcs.bucket(`aBucket`)
let cloudFile = bucket.file(`aFile`)
```

I would like to get the URL for downloading `cloudFile`.

Comment: It's storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>.

Comment: @jarmod Wanna write this as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a variety of [request URIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-uris), including `storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>`.

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a convenience method or property to get this programmatically, like `cloudFile.url`.

Comment: Looks like 5 years later there is, make sure to see below @Ivan's answer

Answer (score 1):

If file is public, then you can use a corresponding method:

```
cloudFile.publicUrl()
```